Orthogonal circle iff passes through harmonic conjugate

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a circle of center $O$ and $P \neq O$ a point that doesn't belong to $\mathcal{C}$. Suppose that a line $r$ passing through $P$ intersects $\mathcal{C}$ at $R,S$ and let $Q$ be harmonic conjugate of $P$ wrt to the pair $R,S$, i.e., $$\frac{PR}{RQ}\frac{SQ}{QS}=-1$$
Furthermore, let $\mathcal{D}$ be a circle passing through $P$ with center on the line $r$.


Show that $\mathcal{D};\mathcal{C}$ are orthogonal iff $\mathcal{D}$ passes through $Q$.

Firstly, I was trying to show that if $\mathcal{D}$ passes through $Q$, it'd be orthogonal to $\mathcal{C}$; if $O'$ is the center of $D$, I was thinking of arriving at the equality $\overrightarrow{O'R} \cdot \overrightarrow{O'S}=\big(\frac{\overline{PQ}}{2}\big)^2$ and using that $\frac{\overrightarrow{PR}}{\overrightarrow{QR}}=-\frac{\overrightarrow{PS}}{\overrightarrow{QS}}$; but I haven't found a way to do it.
